# Text in list of figure does not fit the line

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

When I use the code below, the output is OK,

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=10cm]{Students_job1.pdf}
\caption{Bar chart of conditional probabilities of $Students\_job$ given $Student's\_income$}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

but the list of figures is not OK. The text showing this plot's caption does not fit the line. Here is the output.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use math mode for italic text? Letter spacing is not correct. Just using the following should solve the problem:

```
\caption{Bar chart of conditional probabilities of \emph{Students\_job} given \emph{Student's\_income}}
```

Comment: It solved the problem for Figure 6.11, but not for Figure 6.12. Any idea why?

Comment: *A priori*, no. Could you post a minimal full example code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I created a minimal example in which the code perfectly works, but not in my original document. Could it be some other package causing the problem?

Comment: Or a macro. Try with the original preamble, and comment everything, except what's necessary to compile. Then gradually uncomment the preamble, until the problem re-appears. to find the culprit.